# User Defined Exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception

I am learning on how to create a userdefined exceptions in python. I have created a exceptions with various types of exceptions and each one has its one error msg and must have a code to be sent as a response/error. After lot of reading, I am able to send error msg [custom msg] but struggling to send a code along with it. Here are my examples:

**Exception Class**

```
class UserAccessibilityError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, e:Exception, msg=None,debug=None):
        if msg is None:
            msg = " User authentication failure"
        super(UserAccessibilityError, self).__init__(msg)
        self.e = e
        self.retryable = 'N'
        self.item = " User authentication failure"
```

**Code Inherting the exception class**

```
try:
    ...
    ...
    ...
except Exception as error:
    msge = str(error).lower()
    if message.__contains__("user") and message.__contains__("is not authorized to assume iam role"):
       raise UserAccessibilityError(error)
    ...
    ...
```

The above code is deployed in **AWS Lambda** and when the exception with *is not authorized to assume iam role* is met, exception **UserAccessibilityError** is raised with below response.

```
{
  "errorMessage": " User authentication failure",
  "errorType": "UserAccessibilityError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

however I want the response to be having status code along with the keys above from the response. Something like this below. The key `errorcode` is something that must be added by me either in exception or somewhere else where exception is called. Now can someone guide me how I can add the `errorcode` exception being thrown.

```
{
  "errorMessage": " User authentication failure",
  "errorcode" : "4XX"
  "errorType": "UserAccessibilityError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

**Note** The response I have shared is from **AWS Lambda** response whereas response from terminal could be different but I guess that shouldnt affect the solution I am striving for.

Thanks.

Comment: Pls, can someone assist on this? I welcome the solution even if its not for AWS Lambda.

Comment: did you try just adding `statusCode` field in the exception?